# UITableView: Does dequed cells removed when reloadData called?

Tags: ios, uitableview

When an application calls `reloadData` method on `UITableView`, doeas previously dequed cells removed or are they still kept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will keep the visible cells.
If the cell is made in `Storyboard` it will stay there always dequeued.
Reloading the table view clears current state, including the current selection. However, if you explicitly call `reloadData()`, it clears this state,

> any subsequent direct or indirect call to layoutSubviews() does not
>   trigger a reload

.
[Here is link to Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

`reloadData` dequeues new cells for the visible rows and removes the previous cells.